# 3B+ won't boot from USB Hard Drive

Tags: usb, boot, pi-3b+, boot-issues, hard-drive

I flashed Raspbian to a 1TB Samsung Hard drive, and when I try to boot it using a USB hard drive reader (which gets power from a barrel connector), The red light turns on, But there is no Yellow indicator light, and it doesn't show anything on the screen.

```
I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+
I downloaded the Torrent version
I flashed it using balenaEtcher
There is no other USB's plugged in (so no keyboard or mouse)
USB Hard Drive plugged into Bottom left USB port
USB Hard drive is a LaCinema by LaCie
Hard drive is Samsung HD103SI 1TB
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I flashed Raspbian" how? "here is no Yellow indicator light" - there isn't one. Does it boot from a SD Card? if so can you see the USB Hard Drive if you connect it?

Comment: "How?" I used Balena Etcher. It said it was an abnormally large drive, but I ignored that. (it was just telling me that if i want to flash to it, I might want to back up important data)

Comment: " there isn't a yellow indicator light" have you heard of the light next to the red power light?

Comment: it's green not yellow :p

Comment: `USB Hard drive is a LaCie LaCinema` is that the USB to SATA adapter, not a hard drive? right? or are you trying with two different hard drives?

Comment: you also failed to answer the most important question ... *Does it boot from a SD Card? if so can you see the USB Hard Drive if you connect it?*

Comment: Yes it does boot from an SD card, yes it's the USB to SATA adapter.